# What exactly does the Lua Programming WikiBooks mean by "Instructions"

Tags: lua, wiki

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Programming/Statements says:

> Statements are pieces of code that can be executed and that contain an
> instruction and expressions to use with it. Some statements will also
> contain code inside of themselves that may, for example, be run under
> certain conditions. Dissimilarly to expressions, they can be put
> directly in code and will execute.

What does it mean by instructions?
Am I looking too deep in to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article seems very poorly written in general. Containing gems like "Assignment is [...] used to assign". Your confusion is probably also just a result of this awkward style. The way I read it, the book separates between:

- Statements: Do something specific, like adding two values into a variable.
- Instructions: Things you can do in general, like adding any two values.

It seems to suggest a sort of abstraction-application relationship between the two.

That's a very specific way of dividing between the two and it's ultimately very inconsequential, so you can probably treat them as interchangeable while reading that book.